# Enable Camera and Mic access in wkwebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, html, wkwebview

I have a mobile-optimized web app that makes use of `getUserMedia` to access webcam and mic resources.

I'm wrapping this app in a `WKWebView` as I want to offer a native app experience.  I'm aware that iOS doesn't allow camera access via browsers - however is there any way to gain permissions to the webcam/mic with native code (alongside the wrapper) and feed this to the web app - perhaps by somehow pointing `getUserMedia` to a local stream source?

Comment: Were you able to stub getUserMedia in WKWebView?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, take a look at [cordova-plugin-iosrtc](https://github.com/BasqueVoIPMafia/cordova-plugin-iosrtc) and [cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine). The idea behind the plugin is as follows:

**1.** Create a JavaScript file (WebRTC.js) that defines the various WebRTC classes and functions, and passes the calls to the WKWebView, for example:

```
(function() {
  if (!window.navigator) window.navigator = {};
  window.navigator.getUserMedia = function() {
    webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage(arguments);
  }
})();
```

**2.** In the WKWebView, inject the script at the document start:

```
let contentController = WKUserContentController();
contentController.add(self, name: "callbackHandler")

let script = try! String(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "WebRTC", withExtension: "js")!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
contentController.addUserScript(WKUserScript(source: script, injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: true))

let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.userContentController = contentController

webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: config)
```

**3.** Listen for messages sent from the JavaScript:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {
  var webView: WKWebView!

  func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    if message.name == "callbackHandler" {
      print(message.body)
      // make native calls to the WebRTC framework here
    }
  }
}
```

**4.** If success or failure callbacks need to be performed back in JavaScript-land, evaluate the function call directly within the WKWebView:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("callback({id: \(id), status: 'success', args: ...})", completionHandler: nil)
```

These callbacks need to be stored in a hash in the JavaScript *before* calling `postMessage`, then the hash key must be sent to the WKWebView. This is the `commandId` in the plugins.

```
int exec_id = 0;
function exec(success, failure, ...) {
  // store the callbacks for later
  if (typeof success == 'function' || typeof failure == 'function') {
    exec_id++;
    exec_callbacks[exec_id] = { success: success, failure: failure };
    var commandId = exec_id;
  }
  webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage({id: commandId, args: ...})
}

// the native code calls this directly with the same commandId, so the callbacks can be performed and released
function callback(opts) {
  if (opts.status == "success") {
    if (typeof exec_callbacks[opts.id].success == 'function') exec_callbacks[opts.id].success(opts.args);
  } else {
    if (typeof exec_callbacks[opts.id].failure == 'function') exec_callbacks[opts.id].failure(opts.args);
  }
  // some WebRTC functions invoke the callbacks multiple times
  // the native Cordova plugin uses setKeepCallbackAs(true)
  if (!opts.keepalive) delete exec_callbacks[opts.id];
}
```

**5.** Of course add the `NSCameraUsageDescription` and `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` permissions to the `Info.plist` for your project.

Keep in mind this is a non-trivial task, but that's the general idea behind bridging JavaScript, WKWebView, and native framework code with asynchronous callbacks.

Comment: Do you have an example? I'm trying to do this with no success

Comment: Can you please post the example code, would be really helpful.

Comment: Do you have an sample project

Comment: Can you please post sample?

Comment: cordova-plugin-iosrtc contains a fully functional WebRTC interface, so this was more of a tutorial on how to integrate Cordova plugins into a non-Cordova native app.

Comment: how to implement this in react native?

Answer (score 0):

So I've found the solution for WebRTC access now

By config WKWebView to allowInlineMediaPlayback to true

example.

```
internal lazy var webview: WKWebView = {
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
}()
```

Hope this answer will help you and other people.