# iOS swift web view opening camera

Tags: ios, swift

I have a quick question I have been asking this question now for a while and no one can answer me. I have a web based system built in html/css/js and php using mysql database.

along with this system I have a android and iOS web view app `WKWebview`

now the app contains the following information

1. a wkwebview = [completed]
2. push notifications thru the web view [not completed]
3. share functionality [completed]
4. camera access [not completed]
5. uploading image to server [completed]

now my question is how do I open the camera thru the wkwebview in swift. 
I did all the permissions and tried a bunch of code still nowhere.  any one have any advice where to look for this awnser?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916436/enable-camera-and-mic-access-in-wkwebview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable Camera and Mic access in wkwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916436/enable-camera-and-mic-access-in-wkwebview)

Comment: nope I have tried it doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidFoord did you manage to solve it