# Web page cannot access camera in WebView

Tags: ios, webview, camera, wkwebview, sfsafariviewcontroller

There is a web page that **scans qr codes via a camera**.

It works beautifully in iphone's `safari browser` but in a webview or `wkwebview` it does not.

I do not own or control js code, so its hard to tell what it requests. Application itself has all the required permissions for camera - it also has its native qr scanner that works fine.

`SFSafariViewController` feels like an overkill and yet I did not manage to present it in a way that shows non blank screen. WebView's delegate methods are not called when camera is requested by a web page... I am aware of solutions that require to manually open camera on redirect and then pass back content to javascript, but I was expecting everything to work out of the box...

Comment: Possible duplicate?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43945157/4048853

Comment: If you don't control the JS code, but can control the app, create the scanner in native code instead.  Pass whatever you scan to the JS, if you can.