# iOS app can record audio, but in the same iOS app, at the in-app browser audio is not recording

Tags: ios, webrtc, wkwebview

I have an iOS app which has audio record in it, which is recording the audio, after giving microphone permission. But in the same iOS app, in the in-app browser, audio is not recording. What is the issue? Why audio is not recording?

Comment: because you are stopping recording session while you leave recording controller

Comment: microphone access for the app is not enough you need to get permission for wkwebview also.

Comment: @zack - thanks for quick reply. How to get permission for wkwebview also

Comment: i think  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916436/enable-camera-and-mic-access-in-wkwebview) will give you an idea but i am not sure that it's gonna work . since i also had situation to get microphone  access but i couldn't acheive that.