# Xcode WebView Camera Access is Not working

Tags: jquery, swift, xcode, camera, webkit

I am trying to build a simple Application for IOS, which is showing me a Webpage which functions as a QRCode Scanner. When i am visiting the webpage "[qrcodescan.in](https://qrcodescan.in)" with safari on my phone, it accesses my iPhone Camera without any problems.

[image]

And this is how it looks when i Run the Application on my phone.
[image]

So as an application i can't access my phone camera, but on the website via Safari it is accessible.

The following is my Code in Xcode.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController,WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string:"https://qrcodescan.in")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)



    }


}
```

Also I added all Keys into "info.plist" for accessing the Camera function on the Phone.

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Camera Usage</string>

<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} library Usage</string>
```

So i searched a lot on the web to find anything helpful and wasn't successful.
I hope somebody can help me.

Also to mention. I am absolute newbie when it comes to Swift or IOS App development in General.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

WKWebView and the web view in the native Safari don't offer the same APIs (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/134216)). That is the main reason your code doesn't work.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916436/enable-camera-and-mic-access-in-wkwebview/43945157#43945157) on how to access the camera on a WKWebView.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is with Webview not from your app side, ask your backend developer to make Webview compatible for iOS application.